# use of std::function<> in template class

Tags: c++, c++14

I came across below Queue template class,

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
protected:
    // Data
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    typename std::queue<T>::size_type size_max_;

    // Thread gubbins
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable full_;
    std::condition_variable empty_;

    // Exit
    std::atomic_bool quit_{false};
    std::atomic_bool finished_{false};

public:
    Queue(const size_t size_max);

    bool push(T &&data);
    bool pop(T &data);

    // The queue has finished accepting input
    void finished();
    // The queue will cannot be pushed or popped
    void quit();
};



using intQueue = Queue<std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>>
```

and i don't understand the use of `std::function<void(int*)>` in above **using** statement. Why don't we write it as `using intQueue = Queue<std::unique_ptr<int>>` instead.

Comment: It seems to be for a custom deleter for the [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>` is a smart array, and you need to free it is as `delete [] px_`;

Comment: @VictorGubin no, that would be `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. This is a `unique_ptr` to polymorphicly allocated `int`

Comment: @Caleth `int *arr = new int[100]; delete [] arr;` is in it a valid case for C++ ?

Comment: @VictorGubin so? You *can* put an `int[100]` with a function that does `delete[]` into a thing that holds "any pair of pointer to int and deleter", but it certainly isn't the *only* thing you can put there. It's also a bad idea, considering `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 types of `std::unique_ptr`:

- A unique pointer with a destructor that simply calls delete on the owned pointer
- A unique pointer with a custom deleter

Although it is still one class template, both types of `unique_ptr` are not interchangeable.  So a `unique_ptr` defined like `std::unique_ptr<int>` cannot be given a custom deleter, whereas `std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>>` CAN be given a custom deleter.

This is unlike `std::shared_ptr`, for which there is actually only 1 type (per pointee type of course).  So you can have a type `std::shared_ptr<Book>` and still give it a custom deleter.

The reason why this difference is made for `std::unique_ptr` is to minimize memory consumption.  In almost all cases the `unique_ptr` will use the default deleter, and so storing one pointer instead of 2 (the second for the deleter) is sufficient.  Only in those cases where the class template is instantiated with a deleter-template-argument, the type will store 2 pointers.

EDIT:
And of course, don't forget about Brian's remark below: the `std::unique_ptr` without custom deleter is also more efficient since the call to the deleter is 'hard-coded' and thus can be inlined, without having the overhead of a virtual call to the custom deleter.  This makes this `std::unique_ptr` as efficient as calling delete yourself (without the risk of forgetting to call it).

Comment: I think the more important reason is that using `unique_ptr` is intended to be equally efficient as manually calling `delete` on a raw pointer at all points where the pointer goes out of scope. If it had to type-erase its deleter the way `shared_ptr` does, it could not achieve that standard of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function<void(int*)>` is an object that can hold any "void(int*) function"-like value. Notably you can change a `std::function` object to hold different functions and function objects during it's lifetime.

It is used here as the (optional) `Deleter` type parameter for `std::unique_ptr`, which is used to retain knowledge of how to free the raw pointer held by the `std::unique_ptr`.

Adding these things together allows `int`s allocated by different means, requiring different deallocations, to be present in the same queue. This is a similar idea to the `std::pmr` containers.